# Django based on PostGreSql error while executing python manage.py runserver- "raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am creating a Django project based on PostGreSql on Windows OS.

I could successfully download Postgresql (32bits) and psycopg2. I work on a 32 bit Python2.7.9 , and my Postgresql - 9.3.7 32-bits.

1. **import psycopg2** throws NO error.
2. I could find a psycopg2 folder in Python27\Lib\site-packages
3. My settings.py contains the following:

   DATABASES = {
           'default': {
               'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
               'NAME': 'testdb' ,
               'USER': 'postgres',
               'PASSWORD': 'paggu',
               'HOST': 'localhost',
               'PORT': '5432',
           }
       }

But I still get the below error when I try to execute the command- python manage.py runserver or python manage.py syncdb

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL
load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am not sure if I missed on anything.

I looked up on the other Stack Overflow posts regarding this problem but didn't seem to find any solution.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Are you sure the env where the package is installed is the same as the project env?

Comment: No I am not using a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to actually install psycopg2. To find out run the following in a Windows command prompt:

`C:\path\to\project\> python`

Then:

`>>> help("modules")`

If psycopg2 is not in the list, do the following:

**Download**: psycopg2-2.6.2.win32-py2.7-pg9.5.3-release.exe from [HERE](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/), then run the following in a Windows command prompt:

`C:\path\to\project> easy_install /path/to/psycopg2-2.6.2.win32-py2.7-pg9.5.3-release.exe`